# From Excel Table to Data Frame in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I need to generate a Data Frame in R from the below Excel Table.

[image]

Every time I modify one of the values from column ***Value*** the variable **Score** will have a different value (the cell is protected so I cannot see the formula).

The idea is to generate enough samples to check the main sources of variability, and perform some basic statistics.

I think the only way would be to manually modify the variables in the column **Value** and anotate the result from **Score** in the Dataframe.

*The main issue* I am having is that I am not used to work with data that has this format, and because of this I am finding difficult to visualize how should I structure the Data Frame.

I am getting stuck because the variable **Score** depends on 5 different **Stages** (where each one of them has 2 different variables) and a set of dimensions with 7 different variables.

I was trying the way I am used to create Data Frames, starting with the Vectors, but it feels wrong and I cannot see how can I represent this relationships between the different variables.

```
            stage <- c('Inspection','Cut','Assembling','Test','Labelling','Dimensions')

    variables <- c('Experience level', 'Equipement', 'User','Length','Wide','Length Body','Width Body','Tape Wing','Tape Body','Clip)

range <- c('b','m','a','UA','UB','UC') ?? not sure what to do about the range??
```

Could anybody help me with the logic on how this should be modelled?

Comment: If you think of `Score` as a single-value response variable that depends on all the Values, I would suggest creating one row for each `Score` result, and have columns for each of the 17 value inputs. Basically, each `Variable` becomes a column name. The `Stage` is meta-information---you probably want to take it on the `Variable` names for the first 4 stages to avoid duplication.

Comment: Many thanks Gregor, the issue I am having is that I also need to differenciate between Inspection, Cut etc, since I need to see which one of them contributes the most to the **Variance** in the **score** variable. So basically I should be able to see something like the **Test** contributes this much to the variance if the user is *UA*, this much if the user is *UB* etc, this is what is driving me nuts....

Comment: That type of question is much better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). It seems like you have a three-part question: (1) how to speed up or automate changing the values in the spreadsheet; (2) how to store the parameters and `Score` for each of your "experiments" (I suggest @Gregor's comment addresses this well); and (3) how to analyze the resulting data to find your results. Numbers 1-2 are good for SO, but 3 is [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) but [on-topic at CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh Many thanks! I wasn't aware of that website, I will post it there. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Gregor, to resolve your *main issue* consider building a data frame of all needed values in respective columns. Then run each row to produce *Score*.

Specifically, to build needed data frame from inputs in Excel table, consider `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) and `data.frame` constructor on equal-length list or vectors of 17 items:

**Excel Table Inputs**

```
# VECTOR OF 17 CHARACTER ITEMS
stage_list <- c(rep("Inspection", 2),
                rep("Cut", 2),
                rep("Assembling", 2),
                rep("Test", 2),
                rep("Labelling", 2),
                rep("Dimensions", 7))

# VECTOR OF 17 CHARACTER ITEMS
exp_equip <- c("Experience level", "Equipement")

var_list <- c(rep(exp_equip, 3),
              c("User", "Equipement"),
              exp_equip,
              c("Length", "Wide", "Length body", "Width body",
                "Tape wing", "Tape body", "Clip"))

# LIST OF 17 VECTORS
bma_range <- c("b", "m", "a")
noyes_range <- c("no", "yes")

range_list <- c(replicate(6, bma_range, simplify=FALSE),
                list(c("UA", "UB", "UC")),
                replicate(3, bma_range, simplify=FALSE),
                list(seq(6.5, 9.5, by=0.1)), 
                list(seq(11.9, 12.1, by=0.1)),
                list(seq(6.5, 9.5, by=0.1)),
                list(seq(4, 6, by=1)),
                replicate(3, noyes_range, simplify=FALSE))
```

**`Map` + `data.frame`**

```
df_list <- Map(function(s, v, r) 
               data.frame(Stage = s, Variable = v, Range = r, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), 
               stage_list, var_list, range_list, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

# APPEND ALL DFS
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
head(final_df)
#        Stage         Variable Range
# 1 Inspection Experience level     b
# 2 Inspection Experience level     m
# 3 Inspection Experience level     a
# 4 Inspection       Equipement     b
# 5 Inspection       Equipement     m
# 6 Inspection       Equipement     a
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/XAUZB52452)

---

**Score Calculation** *(using unknown score_function, assumed to take three non-optional args)*

```
# VECTORIZED METHOD
final_df$Score <- score_function(final_df$Stage, final_df$Variable, final_df$Range)

# NON-VECTORIZED/LOOP ROW METHOD
final_df$Score <- sapply(1:nrow(final_df), function(i) 
                         score_function(final_df$Stage[i], final_df$Variable[i], final_df$Range[i])

# NON-VECTORIZED/LOOP ELEMENTWISE METHOD
final_df$Score <- mapply(score_function, final_df$Stage, final_df$Variable, final_df$Range)
```